# XmlDocument with Kanji text content is not encoded correctly to ISO-8859-1 using XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, iso-8859-1

I have an `XmlDocument` that includes Kanji in its text content, and I need to write it to a stream using ISO-8859-1 encoding.  When I do, none of the Kanji characters are encoded properly, and are instead replaced with "??".

Here is sample code that demonstrates how the XML is written from the `XmlDocument`:

```
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(mStream,enc);
doc.WriteTo(writer);
writer.Flush();
mStream.Flush();
mStream.Position = 0;
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(mStream, enc);
String formattedXML = sReader.ReadToEnd();
```

What can be done to correctly encode Kanji in this specific situation?

Comment: `?` is the replacement character used when you use the *wrong* codepage for ASCII text, or simply try to output characters that don't exist in that codepage. There are no Kanji characters in ISO-8859-1. Why use ISO-8859-1 when .NET uses Unicode? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is `doc` and why are you trying to convert it to Latin 1 only to read it back as Unicode???

Comment: What application are you using to display results?  A text box will give question marks while a rich text box will not ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the `?` character is showing up because Kanji characters are not supported by the encoding [`ISO-8859-1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), so it substitutes `?` as a *fallback character*.  Encoding fallbacks are discussed in the [Documentation Remarks for `Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx#Remarks):

> Note that the encoding classes allow errors (unsupported characters) to:
>
> - Silently change to a "?" character.
> - Use a "best fit" character.
> - Change to an application-specific behavior through use of the [`EncoderFallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoderfallback.aspx) and [`DecoderFallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoderexceptionfallback.aspx) classes with the U+FFFD Unicode replacement character.

This is the behavior you are seeing.

However, even though Kanji characters are not supported by `ISO-8859-1`, you can get a much better result by switching to the newer `XmlWriter` returned by [`XmlWriter.Create(Stream, XmlWriterSettings)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162617.aspx) and setting your encoding on [`XmlWriterSettings.Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding.aspx) like so:

```
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Encoding = enc,
    CloseOutput = false,
    // Remove to enable the XML declaration if you want it.  XmlTextWriter doesn't include it automatically.
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,  
};
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(mStream, settings))
{
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
}

mStream.Position = 0;
var sReader = new StreamReader(mStream, enc);
var formattedXML = sReader.ReadToEnd();
```

By setting the `Encoding` property of `XmlWriterSettings`, the XML writer will be made aware whenever a character is not supported by the current encoding *and automatically replace it with an XML [character entity reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview)* rather than some hardcoded fallback.

E.g. say you have XML like the following:

```
<Root>
  <string>畑 はたけ hatake "field of crops"</string>
</Root>
```

Then your code will output the following, mapping all Kanji to the single fallback character:

```
<Root><string>? ??? hatake "field of crops"</string></Root>
```

Whereas the new version will output:

```
<Root><string>&#x7551; &#x306F;&#x305F;&#x3051; hatake "field of crops"</string></Root>
```

Notice that the Kanji characters have been replaced with character entities such as `&#x7551;`?  All compliant XML parsers will recognize and reconstruct those characters, and thus no information will be lost despite the fact that your preferred encoding does not support Kanji.

Finally, as an aside note the [documentation for `XmlTextWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) states:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you use the System.Xml.XmlWriter class instead.

So replacing it with an `XmlWriter` is a good idea in general.

Sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9G9afK) demonstrating usage of both writers and asserting that the XML generated by `XmlWriter` is semantically equivalent to the original XML despite the escaping of characters.

Comment: That got it.  Thanks a bunch.  How do I mark this solved?  I don't see any doc for that.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again. Now I just have to figure out how to read in the redirected stdout from an exe, and send it back with the same encoding without knowing if it binary data or text.

Comment: If you remove the line `OmitXmlDeclaration = true,` your XML will contain an XML declaration like so: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><Root>...</Root>`.  Possibly that would help.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/8td1YI