# How can I convert an XElement to a byte array for a PutFile operation?

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, character-encoding, xelement

I need to convert a big `XElement` to a byte array so that it can be uploaded later to a fileshare.  What is the correct method to call to do that?

Below you see the signature of a method `fileShare.PutFile` that is internal:

```
void PutFile(string folder, string fileName, byte[] content);
```

Then given an `XElement xml`, I tried converting it to a byte array by encoding its `XElement.Value` using `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()` as follows:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml.Value);
fileShare.PutFile(folderName, blobName, bytes);
```

I am not so sure xml.Value (XElement.Value) is really what GetBytes method is really needing though.  Is this correct?

To test this, I spun up a console app and put in some fake data.  I did this for the XElement:

```
XElement root = new XElement("Root",
            new XElement("Child1", 1),
            new XElement("Child2", 2),
            new XElement("Child3", 3),
            new XElement("Child4", 4),
            new XElement("Child5", 5),
            new XElement("Child6", 6)
        );
```

Then I tried that line of code putting to a byte array

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(root.Value);
```

Well I guess I forgot that when I step over and see Autos that  bytes variable is  btye[6]  and when I expand - I see that [0] = 49  and so on

Now this may not mean it is not working ... or does it mean that?  How can I interpret the contents of the `bytes` array, to check whether it is correct?

Comment: You can answer this your self for the most part... Is the string in `xml.Value` the information you want to send?

Comment: Well - the definition of Value of XElement is a string that contains all the text of it.    Do I truly know the XElement will get property written to Azure correctly -  I don't know as I never used it before.    Its deep into a workflow that is currently not testable - so unless someone on SO knows, I need to figure that out with a console app

Comment: Unfortunately this question has turned into. "*I need to do something, but I need to know if it works.*" You need to be a little more explicit. What is it exactly do you want from the XML element, What is it do you need to ensure is sent over the wire. What azure method are you actually calling, What do you expect to be the result of that call. Also if you cant write a small test for this yourself, you seemingly have bigger problems.  if you can clear up some of these points, i am sure someone can help you

Comment: @TheGeneral    I created a console app and I put an Update at the bottom of my question.   thx again

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, using `Encoding.Default` is not recommended.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> **Warning**
>
> Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and the default encoding can change on a single computer. If you use the Default encoding to encode and decode data streamed between computers or retrieved at different times on the same computer, it may translate that data incorrectly. In addition, the encoding returned by the Default property uses best-fit fallback to map unsupported characters to characters supported by the code page. For these reasons, using the default encoding is not recommended. To ensure that encoded bytes are decoded properly, you should use a Unicode encoding, such as [UTF8Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding?view=net-5.0) or [UnicodeEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicodeencoding?view=net-5.0). You could also use a higher-level protocol to ensure that the same format is used for encoding and decoding.

**Secondly**, [`XElement.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.value?view=net-5.0) returns

> A String that contains all of the text content of this element. If there are multiple text nodes, they will be concatenated.

Thus if you upload the `Value` you will be stripping away the entire XML markup structure from your file leaving only the plain text.  While you might want to do that, it seems very unlikely.  If you compare the value with the string returned by [`XElement.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XNode_ToString) the difference should be clear.

**Instead**, to convert the XML contents of your `XElement` (including both markup and text) to a byte array, it would be better to [write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.writeto?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XNode_WriteTo_System_Xml_XmlWriter_) your `XElement` directly to a `MemoryStream` using an appropriately configured [`XmlWriterSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings) and return the byte array thereby created.  The following extension method does the job:

```
public static partial class XNodeExtensions
{
    static Encoding DefaultEncoding { get; } = new UTF8Encoding(false); // Disable the BOM because XElement.ToString() does not include it.
    
    public static byte [] ToByteArray(this XNode node, SaveOptions options = default, Encoding encoding = default)
    {
        // Emulate the settings of XElement.ToString() and XDocument.ToString()
        // https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,2004
        // I omitted the XML declaration because XElement.ToString() omits it, but you might want to include it, depending upon your needs.
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = (options & SaveOptions.DisableFormatting) == 0, Encoding = encoding ?? DefaultEncoding };
        if ((options & SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces) != 0)
            settings.NamespaceHandling |= NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates;
        return node.ToByteArray(settings);
    }
    
    public static byte [] ToByteArray(this XNode node, XmlWriterSettings settings)
    {
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
            node.WriteTo(writer);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Now you can format your `XElement` to a UTF8-encoded byte array by doing:

```
var bytes = root.ToByteArray();
```

The extension method has the added advantage that, if you really need to use some encoding other than UTF8, unsupported Unicode characters will be escaped rather than replaced with a fallback as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48418024/3744182) to *[XmlDocument with Kanji text content is not encoded correctly to ISO-8859-1 using XmlTextWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48402686/3744182)*.

```
var bytes = root.ToByteArray(encoding : Encoding.Default);
```

To check for correctness, you could examine the contents of the byte array in the debugger or your console app by decoding it to a string as follows:

```
var resultString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Or with the default encoding:

```
var resultString = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```

You could also [assert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.istrue?view=mstest-net-1.3.2) that the contents of the byte array are correct by parsing the contents back to a new `XElement` and checking that the result is semantically identical to the original by using [`XNode.DeepEquals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals):

```
Assert.IsTrue(
    XNode.DeepEquals(root, 
                     XElement.Load(new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(bytes), encoding))));
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lBpxJI).